# Calling a function of char

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to programming in c++ and we were told to write a code for insertion sort where the array is obtained from a file named test1.txt. The first line of the file is the number of elements in the array and the second line has the array. We were asked to return the array from the file-reading function through a pointer but for the time being I tried it with int. I wrote the following code to get the input from a file but I get an error saying that "test1 was not declared in this scope" I tried this code with creating test1 and writing down the content and displaying it and it worked fine. I want to use this file now. What can be the problem?
I also need the number of elements for the next part of the program so I thought if using it as the first element of the array. Will that work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int read_input_array(char* fileName)
{
  string line1;
  string line2;
  std::vector<int> vect;
  ifstream myfile (fileName);
    getline (myfile,line1);
    int value = atoi(line1.c_str());
    cout << "The number of elements is- "<< value << '\n';
    int val = value;
    int array1[val+1];
    array1[1]=value;
    getline (myfile,line2);
    cout <<"The rest is - " << line2<< '\n';
    myfile.close();

    std::stringstream ss(line2);
    int i;
    int j=2;
    while (ss >> i)
    {
        vect.push_back(i);
        if (ss.peek() == ',')
            {ss.ignore();
            cout <<i <<'\n';
            array1[j] = i;
            j++;}
    }
    for (int a=1; a<value+1 ;a++)
    {
        cout <<array1[a]<<endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
int main ()
{

    read_input_array( *test1.txt);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First glance, change:

```
read_input_array( *test1.txt);
//interpreted as "dereference a pointer called 'txt', which is a member of some object called 'test1', which hasn't been declared".
```

to

```
read_input_array("test1.txt"); //i.e. a string representing the name of the file.
```

Comment: Sorry I can't add much more to this, as I don't have time :(

Comment: That's ok n thanks. Pretty much errors are disappeared :)

Answer (score 1):

Literal strings in C++ are represented as `const char*`s.

So if in your main function you call: `read_input_array("test1.txt");` Then inside your `read_input_array` function `fileName` will hold the value: "test1.txt".

As far as passing the size as the first element of the array, I'd recommend just putting your elements in a `std::vector`. Then you can just call `std::vector`'s `size` method to get the actual size.

Comment: Got it. So what's the difference between const char* and char*  ?

Comment: @S.Dan Essentially `const` gives a variable name to a literal that you can't change, but don't want to type into code over and over. It is also very handy in function parameter definitions cause it tells the caller that their argument will not be changed in the function. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/constants/#const